# Recommendation for architecting batch data transfer from big query to multiple cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm currently trying to find an efficient way of reading data from a table in Big Query to then serve as inputs for my multiple cloud functions. I would then like to have the functions run some processing concurrently.

Any critiques or recommendations would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you perform batch processing, use Batch solution instead of real time services.

- [Vertex AI Batch Prediction](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-create-batch-prediction-job-sample)
- [Cloud Run Jobs (with tasks in parallel)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs)
- [Batch (compute engine)](https://cloud.google.com/batch?hl=en)
- or, my favorite because you already have the data in BigQuery, [BigQuery ML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bqml-introduction) with [custom model](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-tensorflow)

are more suitable for your needs.